# Change SVG fill in a loop

Tags: javascript, svg

I have simple SVG illustration, is there is any way to change it's color constantly ? like a loop non-stop random color change.

here is my svg

```
<svg width="533" height="499" viewBox="0 0 533 499" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it: I'm using colors `hsl` for the fill and I'm animating the hue of the colors using `requestAnimationFrame`. I hope it helps.

```js
let p1 = document.querySelectorAll("path")[0];
let p2 = document.querySelectorAll("path")[1]
let h = 0;

function changeColor(){
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(changeColor);
  h+=.5;
  h2=210+h;
  p1.setAttributeNS(null,"fill", `hsl(${~~h},100%,50%)`);
  p2.setAttributeNS(null,"fill", `hsl(${~~h2},100%,50%)`);
}

changeColor()
```

```html
<svg width="533" height="499" viewBox="0 0 533 499" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M258.089 59.6035C309.803 -3.94652 379.363 78.1818 407.679 127.19C352.338 67.4782 301.718 129.7 287.076 167.787C272.435 205.874 233.694 210.043 205.199 217.679C187.359 222.459 146.446 248.26 128.6 264.085C109.864 289.466 48.3081 292.846 41.8378 268.698C27.0852 213.64 95.5238 148.37 137.644 123.97C163.705 101.458 206.375 123.154 258.089 59.6035Z" fill="blue"/>
<path d="M448.323 394.788C427.389 384.661 420.75 356.279 420.047 343.354C441.009 284.421 527.63 350.762 528.167 368.218C528.703 385.674 474.491 407.447 448.323 394.788Z" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is also very good, i'm studying the code thank you so much for the time you put into fixing this, can i speed it little bit ?

Answer (score 1):

Select the element and recursively call a function that sets the `fill` attribute of the SVG element you want to recolor with a random hex.

```js
const recolor = element => {
  const randomColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
  
  circle.setAttribute('fill', randomColor)
  
  setTimeout(() => recolor(element), 600)
}

recolor(document.querySelector('#circle'))
```

```css
svg circle { 
  transition: fill .5s linear; 
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: sorry Nik i more question if you dont mind can i make the transition between colors more smooth ?

Comment: @TasteofLeaving You can add a CSS transition on the `fill`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks nick and sorry for too many question just trying to learn, sometimes the circle disappear and comes back, it might be the function generates a limited number of hues ?

Comment: @TasteofLeaving I don't know why that would happen but feel free to use it as a launchpad for learning :) Happy bug hunting.

Answer (score -1):

`fill` on `<svg>` doesnot work. Its for its elements. You can change its `background`

```js
    function random_rgba() {
        var o = Math.round, r = Math.random, s = 255;
        return 'rgba(' + o(r()*s) + ',' + o(r()*s) + ',' + o(r()*s) + ',' + r().toFixed(1) + ')';
    }
    function changeColor(){
     document.querySelector('svg').style.background = random_rgba();
    }
    setInterval(changeColor,200);
```

```html
<svg width="533" height="499" viewBox="0 0 533 499" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```